# C++ - Is it possible to check derived class type in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

In the code that is below I want to count the number of occurrences of objects of `class B` from the `std::vector` using `dynamic_cast` conversion. But the **result is 2** and it should be **1**. This happens because `dynamic_cast` checks object of `class D` as an object of `class B` because of the inheritance.

Is there any possible way to check the derived class type for multiple inheritance without having this problem? Is there any Java instanceof equivalent in C++ for this situation?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class Base{

public:  
Base(){};
virtual ~Base(){};
};

class A:public virtual Base{
public:
A() {};
virtual ~A(){};

};

class B:public virtual Base{
public:
B(){};
virtual ~B(){};


};


class D: public A, public B{
public:

D(){};
virtual ~D(){};

};

int main()
{

 int c=0;
std::vector<Base*> v;
std::vector<Base*>::iterator myIt;

v.push_back(new Base());
v.push_back(new A());
v.push_back(new B());
v.push_back(new D());

for(myIt=v.begin(); myIt!=v.end();myIt++)
    if(B* object=dynamic_cast<B*>(*myIt))
        c++;
cout<<c<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is something called as `RTTI` Run Time Type Information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/run-time-type-information 

PS: i'm from Java background

Comment: there are 2 `B`s in the vector (any `D` is a `B`) so the result you get is the correct one

Comment: why do you need this? It smells like a XY problem. If `D`s shouldnt be `B`s then `D` shouldnt publicly inherit from `B`

Comment: I know that D is recognized as B, but this is want I want to find out,  a method to count all B's without interfering with the D's

Comment: the solution is to not make `D` inherit publicly from `B`.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The elegant way to handle this issue is to define some kind of `std::string typeName_;` field in your `Base`. Then every class inheriting from `Base` might set this field to the appropriate name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are relying on RTTI already, so this will not incur much more cost. What you could do is replace the dynamic cast by a call to `typeid`. It will only check for *exact* dynamic type:

```
// At the top
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>

//...

std::type_index const b_ti = typeid(B);

for(myIt=v.begin(); myIt!=v.end();myIt++)
    if(b_ti == typeid(**myIt)) // Need to pass an lvalue of type B, hence the double asterisk
        c++;
```

---

Side note, but you should consider replacing the loop by a range based for loop. It'll make the whole thing more readable:

```
for(Base *item : v)
  if(b_ti == typeid(*item))
    ++c;
```

Or better yet, a named algorithm:

```
c = std::count_if(begin(v), end(v), 
      [&](Base *item) { return b_ti == typeid(*item); }
    );
```